# jquery validation how to hide error message only from specified hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I got form with many fields and one is hidden... on validation 
i use code below to set highlight messages

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    errorElement: "label",
    errorClass: 'profile-error',
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).css("border-color","#d44");
        if($('#checkedhour').val() == "") {
            $('.table tbody td').css("border","solid 1px #d44");
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).css("border-color","#DFD7CA");
    },
});
```

the problem is that error also appear on the field which is hidden...this hidden field...
What should i do to make error message only of hidden field does not appear but keep validation of this field?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" required name="field1" />
  <input type="hidden" required name="field2" />
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

When the both fields are empty the errors messages will appear after both fields as label elements.. i just want the label appear only after not hidden fields.

Comment: Just use `$(element).is(":visible"); `

Comment: Or you may need `if ($(element).attr('type') == 'hidden'){}`

Comment: i don't want hide element which is validated but only the error message...

Comment: Show your form atleast

Comment: Check if it's hidden and only validate if it isn't..

Comment: what do you mean Mattigins?? how you can do that? :) u still want to make actions on existing elements from form, not error elements which are not in form before validation action

Comment: @JohnLouieDelaCruz now u can see above my form :)) i think this how he looks like is not a point, the point is the action of validation which makes error elements...

Comment: Are you using [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) plugin? What is the version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Otherwise i still will be happiest when somebody find solution to make this via jquery validation plugin."*

To control how messages are placed, use the plugin's `errorPlacement` option.  Within a conditional checking if the element is hidden, you can eliminate its message.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ($(element).is(":hidden")) {
        return false; // no message shown
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element); // default message placement
    }
}
```

**Proof of Concept demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/o5pns06x/**

Comment: Thanks. I should know that is the solution. Maybe when i needed help i was too tired for be ably.

u must correct in your code from 'inserAfter' to 'insertAfter'

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I find simple solution that make me happy. :-)

Even when we can't do this thru the jQuery.validate() i just forgot we can still use CSS!

Each created error element, in this case 'label' (as i set via errorElement), have also own attribute "for" which value based on "name" attribute from input field which is validated. So we can simple add to CSS requirment

```
<style type="text/css">
label[for=field2].profile-error {display: none !important;}
</style>
```

Now, only an error label with specified value of "for" attribute will not appear.

Otherwise i still will be happiest when somebody find solution to make this via jquery validation plugin. :))

Comment: You would use the `errorPlacement` option to control which messages are displayed.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33672723/594235).